# What would one call a single item of an inventory?

Tags: plural-forms

What term would one use to describe a single item of an inventory?

Say pens.

If pen1, pen2, pen3, pen4 make an *inventory* of pens, how would I refer a single pen?

Comment: Can you please explain the sentence/context where you are trying to use this word, because otherwise it is very difficult to suggest any word. As it stands, you can say one item, one of the pens etc.

Comment: @Thor Thanks, it is in the context of software I'm developing . I needed a word i could use to differentiate a listing of different items e.g Pen, Pencil, Book, Eraser, from a listing of Inventory for each of those items e.g in the Pen inventory we can have Pen1, Pen2... Pen20 e.tc.

Comment: just say 'program will talk up a inventory(array list) and will extract 'each item of that inventory' and use it for computation'.

Comment: a piece? a specimen? An item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your users what they call it. No point introducing a new term if they already have a term.

That said, computer people often have more precise terminology than users. They may well use a term like "stock item" or "inventory item" to refer both to "pen, product number X17B", referring to all pens of that particular make and model, and also use the same term to refer to an individual pen on the shelf.

I recall having a lengthy conversation once where a user told me that our system had to process "requisitions", that is, requests from the field for a certain item, and that there were two types of "requisitions": "subscriptions", which were requests for some quantity of the item to be sent automatically on a regular schedule; and "requisitions", which were one-time requests. Yes, there are two types of "requisitions": "subscriptions" and "requisitions". I said that this seemed rather confusing. He couldn't comprehend my problem.

Anyway, my point is, if your users don't have distinct words for these two ideas and you need them, just make something up. Like "inventory product" and "inventory item" or some such.

I am not aware of any generally accepted term that distinguishes.

Comment: Thank you, I think i will go with coming up with something like "Inventory Item".

Answer (score 2):

At its most generic, you could use the term 'stock item'.  This would cover pen1, pen2 (or pencil5, or ruler6 etc, etc).

There isn't a term I can think of more specific than that, but you can use the construct in specific contexts eg, stationery stock item, kitchenware stock item etc.

Generally, however, we speak of the thing/item first and its grouping second, therefore, there is plenty of information on things like collective nouns, and ways to group things, but things by themselves are just things, even if they come from a group.  So, if you need to identify that it is a pen from the inventory of pens, there probably isn't a better way than calling it 'a pen from the inventory'.

Comment: I think stock item might work. Would it for the above context, See my comment.

Comment: @watkib Probably. But that is an extremely subjective context. You really should do some simple user testing and see whether your target audience intuitively understands the meaning of the phrase in your context. Also, this is a topic perhaps better suited for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).